# Performing segue on login success

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboard

I am new to swift and iOS. I have started an application.Currently trying perform a segue on login success.

**Main.storyboard**

> Navigation Controller > Login Scene > Dashboard Scene.

[image: Storyboard Screenshot]

On the login scene after submitting login creds I make a Rest API call for verifying credentials. Call is successful I can verify by printing to console. But the segue to the dashboard never happens.

Within success case, I am using

```
print("Successfully logged in")
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login_success", sender: self)
```

The print statement executes but the segue isn't triggered.

Comment: can you show the code or UI

Comment: Make sure segue between Login Scene and Dashboard Scene has an identifier "login_success" in storyboard.

Comment: You might have not implemented correct segue with identifier login_success
Also your method signature is also not good, it should be       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login_success", sender: <Any Sender>).
Please show us your storyboard implementation

Comment: `performSegure`?!? It should be `performSegue`

Comment: Added the screenshot for storyboard. identifier is fine.

Comment: You're doing a push, check if your Navigation Controller is not nil.

Comment: where you set the `login_success` identiier

Comment: is this possible to attach your project

Comment: set it in attribute inspector by clicking the segue @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @jonaszmclaren, can you please explain a bit. I am new to this.

Comment: If you perform a push segue, your Navigation Controller must exist. Put a breakpoint at `performSegue()` and when debugger hits the breakpoint write `po navigationController` in the console and check, whether it prints an object or nil.

Comment: Have you made sure that your network operation completion handler is on the main queue? Try a `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.performSegue ... }`

Comment: I second Paul's thought u might be calling perform segue on background thread. UIOperations should only be performed on main thread.

Comment: @Paulw11 & Sandeep, Your solution works. Although it worked and I have a little understanding of what sandeep explained. I will surely learn how it worked. It would be great to if you guys can refer some good resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All operations that affect the UI must be performed on the main queue. Many network operations execute on a background queue and dispatch the completion handler block on that background queue.

A classic symptom of not using the main queue for UI updates is delayed or missing updates.

You can use

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login_success", sender: self)
}
```

To explicitly dispatch the code on the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

On the Storyboard click on segue, and in right upper corner add identifier

```
login_success
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. It's there.